# Add Message Inspector for methods with attribute

Tags: .net, wcf, idispatchmessageinspector

Is it possible to only have a message inspector on certain service methods which have a custom attribute applied to them? All of the examples I've seen online add a message inspector as a behavior extension which gets applied to every method on the service.

Comment: If you're going to down vote and close at least leave a comment as to why.

Comment: This seems like a valid question to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible to apply the inspector to only a limited set of methods however you could try creating a regular message inspector which would check whether the target method has a custom attribute applied:

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
{
        string actionName = request.Headers.Action.Substring(request.Headers.Action.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(actionName))
        {
            var methodInfo = instanceContext.Host.Description.ServiceType.GetMethod(actionName);
            if (methodInfo != null)
            {
                var customAttributes = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(false);
                if (customAttributes.Any(ca => ca.GetType().Equals(typeof(MyCustomAttribute))))
                { 

                }
            }
        }
        ...
```

This is just a quick and dirty implementation you'll probably want to refactor a bit. You might also want to abstract away the filtering process outside the inspector itself, maybe have a Chain of Responsibility of some kind to handle it. Hope that helps.

Comment: This is what I was thinking I just wish there was a cleaner way. Something like a cross between a parameter inspector and a message inspector would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. You need a class that inherits from soapextension and another that inherits from soapexstensionattribute. The soapextensionattribute class is then what you use to set the attributes on the web service method.

For example

' Define a SOAP Extension that traces the SOAP request and SOAP response
    ' for the XML Web service method the SOAP extension is applied to.
    ' //blog.encoresystems.net/articles/how-to-capture-soap-envelopes-when-consuming-a-web-service.aspx
    ' and //bytes.com/topic/net/answers/426481-how-log-soap-messages-client-side
    ' and //www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/SerializationFun.aspx
    Friend Class SoapdbTraceExtension
        Inherits SoapExtension

```
    Private _originalStream As Stream
    Private _newStream As Stream

    Private _methodname As String

    Sub New()
    End Sub

    ' Save the Stream representing the SOAP request (or SOAP response) into
    ' a local memory buffer.
    ' basically due to the nature of streams, this creates a copy so that 
    ' we have something that we can work on. This function is called automatically
    ' when this soapextension is invoked.
    ' see //msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164007.aspx
    ' the goal here is to save the stream containing the SOAP message
    ' We also create a NewStream for holding a working copy of the message
    ' The stream passed into Chainstream creates a memory stream and passes it back to the caller
    ' the stream returned from chainstream contains the serialised SOAP message
    Public Overrides Function ChainStream(ByVal stream As Stream) As Stream

        ' this is called prior to BeforeDeserialize and BeforeSerialize 
        ' see http://hyperthink.net/blog/inside-of-chainstream/
        ' In the former case (i.e. the one we are interested in here
        ' oldstream contains the contents of the soap request and newstream will be empty

        _originalStream = stream
        _newStream = New MemoryStream()
        Return _newStream
    End Function

    ' When the SOAP extension is accessed for the first time, the XML Web
    ' service method it is applied to is accessed to store the parameter values
    ' passed in, using the corresponding SoapExtensionAttribute.  So in the case 
    ' of the database trace this might be the method name (as shown below)
    Public Overloads Overrides Function GetInitializer(ByVal methodInfo As  _
                                                          LogicalMethodInfo,
                                                       ByVal attribute As SoapExtensionAttribute) As Object
        ' We use this to establish
        ' the method name (though it could be any attribute from the
        ' SOAPDatabaseTrace class) i.e. any attribute that can be 
        ' passed from the use of the attribute on the web service method declaration

        ' here we store the name of the method in the property we have setup

            ' name of the calling method

            Me._methodname = CType(attribute, SOAPDatabaseTrace).Method

            Return _methodname

    End Function


    Public Overloads Overrides Function GetInitializer(ByVal webServiceType As  _
                                                          Type) As Object

        Return _methodname
    End Function

    ' Receive the method name stored by GetInitializer and store it in a
    ' member variable for this specific instance.
    Public Overrides Sub Initialize(ByVal initializer As Object)

        ' this is called once per soap request and is therefore the ideal place to add appropriate data

            _methodname = CStr(initializer)


    End Sub


    ' This is automatically called after the chainstream function.
    ' this is called multiple times
    Public Overrides Sub ProcessMessage(ByVal message As SoapMessage)
            Select Case message.Stage
                Case SoapMessageStage.BeforeSerialize
                    ' chainstream is called prior to BeforeSerialize
                Case SoapMessageStage.AfterSerialize
                    WriteOutput(message)

                Case SoapMessageStage.BeforeDeserialize
                    ' chainstream is called prior to BeforeDeserialize 
                    WriteInput(message)
                Case SoapMessageStage.AfterDeserialize
            End Select
    End Sub

    ' Write the SOAP response to the database
    Public Sub WriteOutput(ByVal message As SoapMessage)

            CopyAndKeepXMLStream(_newStream, _originalStream)
    End Sub

    ' Write the SOAP request message to the database

    Public Sub WriteInput(ByVal message As SoapMessage)

            CopyAndKeepXMLStream(oldStream:=_originalStream, cleanedUpStream:=_newStream)

    End Sub

    Private Sub CopyAndKeepXMLStream(ByVal oldStream As Stream, ByVal cleanedUpStream As Stream)

            ' from //google-api-adwords-dotnet.googlecode.com/svn-history/r50/trunk/src/lib/TraceExtension.cs
            Dim oldposition As Long
            If oldStream.CanSeek Then
                oldposition = oldStream.Position
                oldStream.Position = 0
            End If
            ' load the XML writer
            Dim xmlwriter As XmlTextWriter = New XmlTextWriter(cleanedUpStream, Encoding.UTF8)
            ' pretty it all up
            xmlwriter.Indentation = 2
            xmlwriter.IndentChar = Char.Parse(" ")
            xmlwriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented

            ' load from old stream and write to the new cleaned up stream
            Dim xmlreader As XmlReader = New XmlTextReader(oldStream)
            Dim xml As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
            xml.Load(xmlreader)
            xml.WriteTo(xmlwriter)
            xmlwriter.Flush()
            cleanedUpStream.Flush()

            If cleanedUpStream.CanSeek Then
                cleanedUpStream.Position = 0
            End If

            If oldStream.CanSeek Then
                oldStream.Position = oldposition
            End If
            'Dim result As String
            'result = xml.OuterXml

            ' now we have the string we can write to the database
            StoreSOAP(xml)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Parse and store the soap message 
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="xml">The SOAP message</param>
    ''' <remarks>Stores the SOAP message in a database</remarks>
    Private Sub StoreSOAP(ByVal xml As XmlDocument)
```

... standard DB Insert code

```
  End Sub


    Private Sub Copy(ByVal fromStream As Stream, ByVal toStream As Stream)
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(fromStream)
        Dim writer As New StreamWriter(toStream)
        writer.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd())
        writer.Flush()
    End Sub
End Class

' Create a SoapExtensionAttribute for our SOAP Extension that can be
' applied to an XML Web service method.
' these are the attributes we have available
' they are available in the web service of interest
' and can be used here for logging etc.
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)>
Friend Class SOAPDatabaseTrace
    Inherits SoapExtensionAttribute

    Private _mPriority As Integer
    Private _mMethod As String = "Unknown"

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ExtensionType() As Type
        Get
            Return GetType(SoapdbTraceExtension)
        End Get
    End Property


    ''' <summary>
    '''     Priority
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value>Integer</value>
    ''' <returns>
    '''     Indicates the priority in which the extension will be executed relative to other soapextensions.
    '''     1 is the highest priority
    ''' </returns>
    ''' <remarks>Required by the inheritance</remarks>
    Public Overrides Property Priority() As Integer
        Get
            Return _mPriority
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _mPriority = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Method() As String
        Get
            Return _mMethod
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _mMethod = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

then in your web service the method looks something like this

```
    <WebMethod(Description:="Some web method"), _
    SOAPDatabaseTrace(method:="MyFunction")> _
    Public Function MyFunction(ByVal Param1 As String) as object
```

...

You put the SOAPDatabaseTrace attribute onto any method you want to trace